# Gatsby audit on 0 performance due to text compression

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Can anyone advise what i'm doing wrong with this build? I have just finished my Gatsby website and when i run an audit on localhost i'm getting a 0 performance rating and 90% of the savings are coming from `Enable text compression` with again 90% coming from the `/common.js(localhost)` file. Is there a plugin which i should be using to help compress these files or something else which i should be doing?

I have created a few other standard Reactjs websites and not had this issue with them before.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running in development mode, Gatsby is doing a lot of things to make your life easier (live preview, hot reloading, etc.) so the js payload is very big – 8mb in your case.

To test your site performance you should build your site in production mode with `gatsby build` and then serve it with `gatsby serve`.

From Gatsby docs:

> The gatsby develop command doesn’t perform some of the production
>   build steps that the gatsby build command does. Instead, it starts up
>   a development server that you can use to preview your site in the
>   browser — like a runtime.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/